# Binary file handler not writing the last value

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, read-write

I wrote a small file handler class in C++

It has a base class that manages the RAII file closing, and two derived classes one for writing and one for reading. The derived classes have 2 methods write or read value and write or read vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


class File{
protected:
    std::streampos offset;
    std::fstream file;

public:
    File(){
        offset = 0;
    }

    virtual ~File(){
        file.close();
    }
};

class oFile : public File{
public:
    oFile(std::string const& filename) {
        file.open(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void write_value(T value){
        file.seekp(offset);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&value), sizeof(T));
        offset += sizeof(T);
        std::cout<< "wrote a value: " << value << "  current offset: " << offset << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void write_vector(std::vector<T> v){

        write_value(v.size());

        std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [this](T& i){write_value(i);});
    }
};

class iFile : public File{
public:

    iFile(std::string const& filename){
        file.open(filename, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void read_value(T& v){
        file.seekg(offset);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&v), sizeof(T));
        offset += sizeof(T);
        std::cout << "value read: " << v << " current offset: " << offset << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void read_vector(std::vector<T>& v){
        typename std::vector<T>::size_type vsize;
        read_value(vsize);

        std::cout << "size of vector: " << vsize << std::endl;

        for(typename std::vector<T>::size_type i = 0; i < vsize; ++i){
            T value;
            read_value(value);

            v.push_back(value);
        }
    }
};
```

To test the classes I wrote this function:

```
    oFile file("test.ndf");

    double b = 12.;
    file.write_value(b);

    std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3., 4., 6., 10., 15.};

    file.write_vector(v);

    iFile ifile("test.ndf");

    double ib;
    ifile.read_value(ib);

    std::cout << ib << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> iv;
    ifile.read_vector(iv);

    std::cout << "vector size: " << iv.size() << std::endl;

    for(auto val : iv){
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "last val: " << iv[iv.size() - 1] << std::endl;
}
```

But the output has a problem

```
wrote a value: 7 offset: 12
wrote a value: 1 offset: 20
wrote a value: 2 offset: 28
wrote a value: 3 offset: 36
wrote a value: 4 offset: 44
wrote a value: 6 offset: 52
wrote a value: 10 offset: 60
wrote a value: 15 offset: 68 <--- tells me he wrote 15
value read: 12 offset: 8
12
value read: 7 offset: 12
size of vector: 7
value read: 1 offset: 20
value read: 2 offset: 28
value read: 3 offset: 36
value read: 4 offset: 44
value read: 6 offset: 52
value read: 10 offset: 60
value read: 10 offset: 68 <--- problem
vector size: 7
1 2 3 4 6 10 10 last val: 10 <--- last value should be 15
Hello world!
```

The last line of the output is the vector content, and the last value is repeated although in the write method tells me it wrote the right value (15).

I don't understand why it writes or read the last value 2 times? Is my file handler solution good? Is there a better way?

compiled with Code::Blocks (v20.03) using MinGW (v9.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my file handler solution good?

[RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for management of resources is a good and recommended way.

However, with RAII, the scope (and hence the life-time) of variables should be considered even more carefully.

In the exposed code of OP:

```
int main()
{
    oFile file("test.ndf");

    double b = 12.;
    file.write_value(b);

    std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3., 4., 6., 10., 15.};

    file.write_vector(v);

    iFile ifile("test.ndf");

    double ib;
    ifile.read_value(ib);

    std::cout << ib << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> iv;
    ifile.read_vector(iv);

    std::cout << "vector size: " << iv.size() << std::endl;

    for(auto val : iv){
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "last val: " << iv[iv.size() - 1] << std::endl;
} // <-- all local variables incl. file will be destroyed here
```

the `ofile file` instance lives until end of `main`.

```
wrote a value: 12  current offset: 8
wrote a value: 7  current offset: 16
wrote a value: 1  current offset: 24
wrote a value: 2  current offset: 32
wrote a value: 3  current offset: 40
wrote a value: 4  current offset: 48
wrote a value: 6  current offset: 56
wrote a value: 10  current offset: 64
wrote a value: 15  current offset: 72
value read: 12 current offset: 8
12
value read: 7 current offset: 16
size of vector: 7
value read: 1 current offset: 24
value read: 2 current offset: 32
value read: 3 current offset: 40
value read: 4 current offset: 48
value read: 6 current offset: 56
value read: 10 current offset: 64
value read: 10 current offset: 72
vector size: 7
1 2 3 4 6 10 10 last val: 10
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e90cc96f85088bec) (where I reproduced the issue of OP).

As the internal stream is closed in the destructor of `ofile`, there might be internally buffered (i.e. unflushed) contents upto this point although the stream will report them as written.

The solution is simple: **The scope of `ofile file` has to be limited.**

The fixed code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3., 4., 6., 10., 15.};

    { // start new scope
        oFile file("test.ndf");

        double b = 12.;
        file.write_value(b);

        file.write_vector(v);
    } // close scope -> destroy file (and b)

    iFile ifile("test.ndf");

    double ib;
    ifile.read_value(ib);

    std::cout << ib << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> iv;
    ifile.read_vector(iv);

    std::cout << "vector size: " << iv.size() << std::endl;

    for(auto val : iv){
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "last val: " << iv[iv.size() - 1] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
wrote a value: 12  current offset: 8
wrote a value: 7  current offset: 16
wrote a value: 1  current offset: 24
wrote a value: 2  current offset: 32
wrote a value: 3  current offset: 40
wrote a value: 4  current offset: 48
wrote a value: 6  current offset: 56
wrote a value: 10  current offset: 64
wrote a value: 15  current offset: 72
value read: 12 current offset: 8
12
value read: 7 current offset: 16
size of vector: 7
value read: 1 current offset: 24
value read: 2 current offset: 32
value read: 3 current offset: 40
value read: 4 current offset: 48
value read: 6 current offset: 56
value read: 10 current offset: 64
value read: 15 current offset: 72
vector size: 7
1 2 3 4 6 10 15 last val: 15
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc7ee3220c5eaeb2)

---

> I don't understand why it writes or read the last value 2 times?

This wasn't clear to me too until I realized that I focused too much on *read the last value 2 times*.

Actually, it doesn't – **it just fails to read the last value and reports erroneously the previous value again**.

To check this out, I added a minimal "error handling" in `iFile::read_value`:

```
    template <typename T>
    void read_value(T& v){
        file.seekg(offset);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&v), sizeof(T));
        if (!file) std::cerr << "AARG! Input failed. :-(\n";
        offset += sizeof(T);
        std::cout << "value read: " << v << " current offset: " << offset << std::endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
wrote a value: 12  current offset: 8
wrote a value: 7  current offset: 16
wrote a value: 1  current offset: 24
wrote a value: 2  current offset: 32
wrote a value: 3  current offset: 40
wrote a value: 4  current offset: 48
wrote a value: 6  current offset: 56
wrote a value: 10  current offset: 64
wrote a value: 15  current offset: 72
value read: 12 current offset: 8
12
value read: 7 current offset: 16
size of vector: 7
value read: 1 current offset: 24
value read: 2 current offset: 32
value read: 3 current offset: 40
value read: 4 current offset: 48
value read: 6 current offset: 56
value read: 10 current offset: 64
AARG! Input failed. :-(
value read: 10 current offset: 72
vector size: 7
1 2 3 4 6 10 10 last val: 10
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddd0d61b6a726ea5)

Of course, file I/O is something which may fail for various reasons. So, success of file operations should be checked always.

Comment: Thank you! I was driving crazy as like you I was concentrating on the read last value. I actually checked the file if it failed on open, I wouldn't have imagined that would fail after the read. Thank you for the extra work on explaining the scope!

Comment: @Pella86 Opening a file is only one operation which may fail but reading/writing may fail also and, hence, should be checked for success as well. This is still true assuming your file I/O is super-proofed. There are possible reasons beyond your reach - e.g. a disk volume which is exceeded before you could complete the file, or just a stupid user which pulls out the USB stick before it was synced... ;-)

Comment: @Pella86 Actually, relying on RAII in std::streams is a bit dangerous as well. A stream should be closed (or flushed) explicitly (before destruction) to notice errors (e.g. while flushing the last buffered contents). After destruction, this isn't anymore possible. The stream state is beyond of reach (of course) and even if exceptions were enabled for the stream - they are catched silently in the stream  destructor because destructors should never throw.